# Warning when building app: "Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow."

Tags: android, android-studio, warnings, ads, tapjoy

I have a project on which I worked last year. Recently I started working on it again  but wanted to update everything that was possible. I managed to resolve basically all problems except this one. I can't find anything online about this warning. I get it when I build the project. I tried downloading and using the latest tapjoy jar but it still appears. In the warning there is a path to a cache folder so I tried deleting it but id didn't change anything; maybe I'm getting this warning because those folders are missing?

The full warning is like this:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\black\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\91514d5ad9a3a762574d6c5e2880beba\\transformed\\jetified-tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
```

The problem is that i have around 200 lines of this warning in console and I would like to solve them.

Has anyone seen this warning before and knows how to fix it? Obviously any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing folder should have nothing to do with this warning. I had this problem in the process of writing custom gradle plug-ins. It seems that `ClassWriter` or `ClassVisitor` in ASM did not implement any method, there will be this warning, but that does not affect normal functionality. You can check that your project has used those gradle plug-ins, perhaps these plug-ins are caused by the update of the problem.